# Entity Framework AddOrUpdate Duplicate PK Inner Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a basic web api app that uses entity framework. I am receiving hundreds of events from an api every hour and a few of them are causing an error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.ApiTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ApiTable'. The duplicate key value is (123456).
> The statement has been terminated.

I have a processor that handles the call to a generic repository that uses `AddOrUpdate` to avoid duplicate PK.

The processor:

```
 using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
 {
      unitOfWork.ApiTableRepository.AddOrUpdate(apiTable);

      await unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
 }
```

And the repository:

```
    public virtual void AddOrUpdate(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.AddOrUpdate(entityToUpdate);
    }
```

I also log everytime an event is received, as well as the PK of that event, and it appears that it could have something to do with multiple events of same PK in the same timeframe, though the `AddOrUpdate` should still take care of that I thought. Here are logs of the event that failed:

> 09:36:31.979 2017-09-29 [22] INFO  - Received event, PK: 123456
>
> 09:36:31.994 2017-09-29 [9] INFO  - Received event, PK: 123456
>
> 09:36:32.026 2017-09-29 [9] ERROR - An error occured attempting to process PK: 123456

Comment: This sounds like a race condition. I'm assuming `AddOrUpdate` checks if something exists before adding it. That's not enough, unless you lock the table prior to the check. Otherwise, another request might insert the object after the check and before the insertion.

Comment: Just to verify, the 123456 number in the exception message is a value you placed in there before posting on SO right? (in real scenario it is different everytime?)

Comment: @TravisActon Yes I replaced the PK before posting, but an event can be sent to update a record, such as this scenario, so the same PK is used

Comment: So you don't have an identity column as PK? Or actually I'm asking: why not?

Comment: @GertArnold The issue I ran into was that if I let EF handle the ID, when a future event came through, let's say 3 weeks later, to update the event, it is alot easier when the event contains the PK. If EF assigned an ID, obviously the event coming in doesn't contain that and i'd have to do a query

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that, so let's be clear about the mechanism. If EF inserts an entity --and the table has an identity column-- the *database* assigns the new ID value (and guarantees it's unique, irrespective of concurrency). EF reads the generated value into the entity during `SaveChanges`, so you don't need an extra query. So after `SaveChanges` your new event entities (in C#) will have their generated ID values.

Comment: @GertArnold To clarify, I have events coming in for an object that can either be inserted or updated. If an event comes in to update something in my DB, the event isn't going to contain anything to identify which record it wants to update. So instead of running a query on something unique in the event to find it in the DB, I simply use that unique value as the PK